# Setting properties of object to undefined deallocates memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, ecmascript-6

I have a lot of collections with a lot of records and I need to manage them, loading and unloading them depending on what I think the user is going to need.

The collections look like:

```
{
    users {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Jhon',
        },
        2: { ... },
        ...
    },
    products: { ... }
}
```

I am using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) so I cannot mutate the collections to make changes on them, I have to redeclare them. Now I need to purge the users collection from all the users, except the one that is logged into the application.

To do this I assign undefined to all of the users to purge, the operation I do is something like this (of course I don't manually write every ID):

```
{
    users: { 
        ...users, 
        1: undefiend, 
        2: users[2],
        3: undefined
        ... 
    }
}
```

**¿Does this properly deallocate the memory used by the whole collection?**

Comment: Yes if there is no other reference to that value.

Comment: null should deallocate as well, and is at least in my books more `proper` way to solve it. Somebody correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Dellirium i personally prefer `undefined`, as the language does not use `null` at all, if you don't use `null`, you can use `something === undefined` withouth having to worry about `null` and avoiding the evil `==`

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo i would recommend to use avoid the use of undefined and let to be handle by the results of the language and use null.